# HttpClient : HttpRequestException connection closed when using some proxy

Tags: c#, http, exception, proxy, httpclient

I'm developping an application which will need to run Http requests using some proxies. We have many proxy providers but we have some problem with one of them :

I use HttpClient to run the requests, to avoid problems from the requested server I do all my tests by calling a personal IIS home page on which there is no specific security :

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpClientRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string userAgent)
{
    HttpResponseMessage? response;
    // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
    
    var pwd = "*********";
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("mylogin", pwd);
    var proxy = new WebProxy("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 12345)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = credentials,
    };
    
    using var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        Proxy = proxy,
        UseProxy = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false
        //CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
        // ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
        // ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, certificate2, arg3, arg4) => true,
        // AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All, 
        // AllowAutoRedirect = true, 
        // SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
    };
    using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderNames.UserAgent, userAgent);
    //request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(HeaderNames.Referer, url);

    foreach ((string? key, string? value) in headers
                 .Where(h => h.Key != HeaderNames.UserAgent && h.Key != HeaderNames.Referer))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(key, value);
    }

    response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    return response;
}
```

When I call this method with almost each proxies, it works perfectly. But If I use a NVPN proxy I'm often able to make one or 2 request and then I get an HttpRequestException for almost all the request using the same proxy.
Here is my test console app :

```
int nbLeft = 0;
int i = 0;

while (true)
{
    i++;
    if (nbLeft <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Nb of call ?");

        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nbLeft);
    }

    nbLeft--;

    Console.WriteLine($"Appel {i:00}");

    try
    {
        await HttpClientRequest(
            "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
            new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Connection", "Keep-Alive" }, { "Keep-Alive", "600" } },
            "Mozilla/5.0 (PlayStation 4 1.52) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko)");

        Console.WriteLine($" => OK");
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
    catch (Exception? e)
    {
        int nbTab = 0;
        while (e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', nbTab * 3)} => ERROR : {e.Message}");
            e = e.InnerException;
            nbTab++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that the second call was OK but 1st and 3rd fail:

> Nb of call ?
> 3
> Appel 01
> => ERROR : An error occurred while sending the request.
>    => ERROR : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
>       => ERROR : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> Appel 02
> => OK
> Appel 03
> => ERROR : An error occurred while sending the request.
>    => ERROR : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
>       => ERROR : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I already tried a lot of things without succeed :

- All the lines in comment have been tested
- I tried to call real websites
- I tried to use Puppeteer => same problem
- Idem with the old HttpWebRequest

But the problem do not come from the proxy because if I set it in a chromium, it ask me for proxy credentials and then it works perfectly.
I'm also able to make it works with postman without any exception.

I think this is a problem with the proxy credentials because if I enter a wrong password I get the same error.